# how can i convert a mouse position to a location?

Tags: vb.net

I want to create a menu wherein i can hover the titles and the contents will be displayed below but the thing is the panel also dissapear when i mouseleave

```
Private Sub Label10_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Panel9.MouseLeave, Label10.MouseLeave
     Dim x As New Point
     x = MousePosition
     If x = Panel7.Location Then
     Else
         Panel9.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(150, Color.White)
         Panel7.Visible = False
     End If
End Sub
```

Comment: something.location = new point(mouse.x mouse.y) ?

Comment: What you're asking is not clear. What is the role of `Panel7`? Is it the container of both `Label10` and `Panel9`? Maybe, post an image of your layout and, possibly, assign meaningful names to your controls.

Comment: The location property is only going to give you the upper left point. Since you're using a mouse I think what you really want to know is if the mouse location is within the said control bounds.

Answer (score 1):

To determine whether your mouse is over a specified control, just do:

```
If myControl.ClientRectangle.Contains(myControl.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition)) Then
    ' Mouse over control
Else
    ' Mouse not over control
End If
```

Whereas you replace `myControl` with any control you'd wish to check whether your mouse is over it.